# Error appending a list to a dictionary, using .append

Tags: python, list, dictionary, praw

I am trying to scrape reddit and I already have a dictionary (reddit_sneaker_info) with the "post titles", "post id", "time/date created", and "number of comments" like this for each shoe:

```
'Puma Clyde Hardwood': [{'Post_title': 'Puma Clyde Hardwood Natural, originally got these to ball in but these definitely looks good for casual use too.',
   'Post_id': 'ki4kfi',
   'Created_at': 1608669448.0,
   'Num_comments': 0}
```

So for each run I would like it to loop through the posts for each shoe and for each post append all the comments to a list (comments_list). I would like to limit the number of comments grabbed to 30 per post.  Then once it has appended all the comments to the comments_list, take the comments_list and add it as a new key called "Comments" to the existing dictionary. So it would look like this:

```
'Puma Clyde Hardwood': [{'Post_title': 'Puma Clyde Hardwood Natural, originally got these to ball in but these definitely looks good for casual use too.',
   'Post_id': 'ki4kfi',
   'Created_at': 1608669448.0,
   'Num_comments': 0,
   'Comments':[(this is where the comments_list would go)]}
```

I've tried a few things I have found on stack overflow but I haven't had any success. The code below was the last thing I had tried and this was a common error I was encountering:

```
---> 33         reddit_sneaker_info[shoe][post].append(comments_list)

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

I'm not sure what else to do and I would really appreciate any help or corrections. Thank you!

```
#loop through each sneaker in the entire set
for shoe in reddit_sneaker_info:
    # for each sneaker extract the id number of the post
    for post in reddit_sneaker_info[shoe]:
        number_of_comments = post["Num_comments"]
        post_id = post["Post_id"]
        # empty list for comments to be re-added in 
        comments_list = []
        if number_of_comments != 0:
            # get the comments by post_id
            submission = reddit.submission(id=post_id)
            submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
            for comment in submission.comments.list():
                comment_count += 1
                # prevent the script from grabbing more than 30 comments
                if comment_count < 30:
                    comment_by_post = comment.body
                    # append each comment text to list
                    comments_list.append(comment_by_post)
                    
                elif comment_count == 30:
                    break
        elif number_of_comments == 0:
            pass
        # append the comment list to the dictionary for that post
        reddit_sneaker_info[shoe][post].append(comments_list)
        post_count += 1
        # hopefully this is enough time in between requests
        time.sleep(45)
    print("Comments grabbed for shoe number {}".format(post_count))
```

edit with more of reddit_sneaker_info, the first two sneakers:

```
{'Gucci Off The Grid High Top': [],
 'OFF-WHITE Odsy 1000': [{'Post_title': 'My first Off-white anything [ODSY-1000]',
   'Post_id': 'f53rvc',
   'Created_at': 1581945615.0,
   'Num_comments': 15},
  {'Post_title': 'Hypebeast couples',
   'Post_id': 'ehl57e',
   'Created_at': 1577735358.0,
   'Num_comments': 12}],
```

Comment: That;s got nothing to do with appending. You should share a little of `redddit_sneaker_info`. It most likely has a list of dicts.

Comment: @BuddyBob I edited the original post with more of the reddit_sneaker_info. You're right it is a list of dictionaries. So does that mean i'd have to go one layer further or how would I go about this?

Answer (score 0):

I decided rather than trying to add it into the existing dictionary it would be just as useful for me to create a new dataframe with the commments. There is probably a better way to do this, but I guess this is a solution. In the dataframe I will also add the shoe name and post id that corresponds with where the comment was grabbed from.

```
comments_list = []
post_id_list = []
shoe_name_list = []

for shoe in reddit_sneaker_info:
    # for each sneaker extract the id number of the post
    for post in reddit_sneaker_info[shoe]:
        number_of_comments = post["Num_comments"]
        post_id = post["Post_id"]
        comment_count = 0
        if number_of_comments != 0:
            # get the comments by post_id
            submission = reddit.submission(id=post_id)
            submission.comments.replace_more(limit=None)
            for comment in submission.comments.list():
                comment_count += 1
                # prevent the script from grabbing more than 30 comments
                if comment_count < 30:
                    comment_by_post = comment.body
                    shoe_name_list.append(shoe)
                    post_id_list.append(post_id)
                    # append each comment text to list
                    comments_list.append(comment_by_post)
                    print('comment added')
                    
                elif comment_count == 30:
                    print('limit of 30 comments reached')
                    break
        elif number_of_comments == 0:
            pass
        post_count += 1
        print("please wait 45 seconds")
        # hopefully this is enough time in between requests
        time.sleep(45)
    print("Comments grabbed for post number {}".format(post_count))
```